# UILabel text updation

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel

I have a`UILabel` which I want to update.

If I will login with a user name then the `UILabel` will be updated with that user name,which it is doing correctly and storing the value.

Now I want whenever i will logout then the `UILabel` text should return the previous value which it stored deleting the new value.

Can you please help me with this.

After login I have updated my UiLabel text like this

```
-(void)updateUserName:(NSNotification*)noti
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [noti userInfo];

    self.user.firstName = [userInfo valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
    self.user.lastName = [userInfo valueForKey:@"LastName"];

    if (self.user.firstName != nil && self.user.firstName.length > 0 && self.user.lastName.length > 0)
    {
        self.userName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.user.firstName, self.user.lastName];
    }
}
```

then after logout I need to retrieve the old data of UiLabel.

Comment: Just add a NSString variable to your view controller class, where you store the UILabel's text in and retrieve it later.

Comment: can i have your code

Comment: After login i have updated my label text like this

Comment: -(void)updateUserName:(NSNotification*)noti
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [noti userInfo];
 
   self.user.firstName = [userInfo valueForKey:@"FirstName"];
    self.user.lastName = [userInfo valueForKey:@"LastName"];
    if (self.user.firstName != nil && self.user.firstName.length > 0 && self.user.lastName.length > 0)
    {
        self.userName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.user.firstName, self.user.lastName];
    }
}

Comment: @SmitaPragyanBiswalCor hi, you can store your username in NSUserDefaults. and when ever you can login check that NSString is empty or not. if not you can assign it to your textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *userName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.user.firstName, self.user.lastName]; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

save username to NSUserdefaults

```
NSString *userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"preferenceName"];
```

Take the username whenever you want and assign it to UILabel name

whenever the user got Logout clear the NSuserdefaults

```
NSString *userName =@""; 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Thanks. From your answer I got some idea.

Comment: Try to implement with it